# MariaDB Created view takes too long

Tags: sql, mariadb, query-optimization, mariadb-10.3

I have a problem. I have a table with 6 million records in it. Every record has a column dateTime, and for my code I need the most recent 16 records in ascending order. This took too long to query directly out of the original table, so I created a view using the following query:

```
SELECT openTime, high, low, a, b, c, d, e FROM  Candlestick WHERE market = 'USDT' AND coin = 'ETH' AND period = '5m' ORDER BY openTime DESC LIMIT 16
```

This means that the view only contains 16 records. Then in my code I use the view with the following query:

```
SELECT high, low, a, b, c, d, e FROM vwCI_USDT_ETH_5m ORDER BY openTime ASC
```

This query takes all (16 records) the records and puts it in ascending order, but even for these 16 rows the query takes roughly 25 seconds shown on the image below:
[image]
Is there a way to speed up this select query?

### UPDATE

I created an index on the Candlestick table like @The Impaler told me to, and I am now using the following query without the view:

```
SELECT a.high, a.low, a.a, a.b, a.c, a.d, a.e FROM (SELECT openTime, high, low, a, b, c, d, e FROM Candlestick WHERE market = 'USDT' AND coin = 'ETH' AND period = '5m' ORDER BY openTime DESC LIMIT 16 ) AS a ORDER BY a.openTime ASC
```

Here are all my indexes now:
[image]
But still after the index, this query takes about 20 - 25 seconds. What can I do to improve it?

The result of `show create table Candlestick;`:

```
CREATE TABLE `Candlestick` (
  `dateTimeChanged` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
  `openTime` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `closeTime` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `market` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `coin` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `period` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `open` decimal(14,6) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.000000,
  `high` decimal(14,6) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.000000,
  `low` decimal(14,6) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.000000,
  `close` decimal(14,6) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.000000,
  `volume` decimal(20,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00000000,
  `a` decimal(6,3) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.000,
  `b` decimal(3,0) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `c` decimal(3,0) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `d` decimal(3,0) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `e` varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ma5` decimal(16,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00000000,
  `ema5` decimal(16,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00000000,
  `ema10` decimal(16,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00000000,
  `ema12` decimal(16,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00000000,
  `ema20` decimal(16,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00000000,
  `ema26` decimal(16,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00000000,
  `ema50` decimal(16,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00000000,
  `ema55` decimal(16,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00000000,
  `ema100` decimal(16,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00000000,
  `ema200` decimal(16,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00000000,
  `rsi14AvgGain` decimal(16,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00000000,
  `rsi14AvgLoss` decimal(16,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00000000,
  `rsi14` decimal(16,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00000000,
  `macd` decimal(16,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00000000,
  `signal` decimal(16,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00000000,
  `bbLower` decimal(16,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00000000,
  `bbMiddle` decimal(16,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00000000,
  `bbUpper` decimal(16,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00000000,
  `dmiDIPositive` decimal(16,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00000000,
  `dmiDINegative` decimal(16,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00000000,
  `dmiADX` decimal(16,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00000000,
  PRIMARY KEY (`openTime`,`market`,`coin`,`period`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `OpenTime` (`openTime`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `MarketCoinPeriod` (`market`,`coin`,`period`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `ix1` (`market`,`coin`,`period`,`openTime`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Show the result of the following: `SELECT version();` and `show create table Candlestick;`

Comment: Version: `10.3.31-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.20.04.1-log`
show create table Candlestick: `CREATE TABLE Candlestick (dateTimeChanged t...`
This is the only thing I get to see, but the create query has `2157` characters, because I have 37 columns!

Comment: Ah. So it's not MySQL.  Use the MySQL command line client to obtain the complete result of: `show create table Candlestick;`

Comment: Ah, I will add it at the bottom of the question!

Comment: The covering index with proper order of the `openTime` column does seem to help.  See the fiddle provided.  It contains a table I created, and the actual table after you provided the detail.  The index isn't usually chosen if the order of `openTime` isn't in the order you need.  MariaDB supports descending indexes to address this case.  *Sorry.  It allows the syntax.  I see some conflicting documentation.*  I don't have definitive detail on that.  But the plan seems to suggest it helped.

Comment: While MySQL 8.0 has this documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/descending-indexes.html  ... I couldn't find the same for MariaDB.  This appears to be an open ticket on this for Maria: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-13756

Comment: I've changed the question title and tags to make it more clear this is a question about MariaDB, not MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A covering index could help.

This is the final suggested index based on the review below:

```
create index ix3 on Candlestick (market, coin, period, openTime DESC, high, low, a, b, c, d, e);
```

Here's all the SQL used in the test case (fiddle):

[Working test case for MariaDB and generated sample data](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=1700ab578d1c3df4b8f296b29ee5dc64)

The following is based on a guess at the actual `create table` statement, but it's useful to discuss some of the possible index issues.

Here's the plan with the current suggested index, and some sample data:

[image]

Here's the plan with the `descending` version of the index:

```
create index ix2 on Candlestick (market, coin, period, openTime DESC);
```

[image]

Here's the suggested covering index:

```
create index ix3 on Candlestick (market, coin, period, openTime DESC, high, low, a, b, c, d, e);
```

[image]

and with your actual table, and the previous `ix1` index:

[image]

Now with the new suggested index (with `openTime DESC` order):

[image]

Update: MariaDB seems to support the descending index syntax, but may not fully support the feature.  In more recent versions of Maria (10.5, for example) the new index (`ix3`) is not used for this test case.

We could `force` the index, if that were found to be helpful:

```
SELECT a.high, a.low, a.a, a.b, a.c, a.d, a.e
  FROM (
         SELECT openTime, high, low, a, b, c, d, e
           FROM Candlestick FORCE INDEX (ix3)
          WHERE market = 'USDT' AND coin = 'ETH' AND period = '5m'
          ORDER BY openTime DESC
          LIMIT 16
       ) AS a
 ORDER BY a.openTime ASC
;
```

If we look at the table after adding the index, we notice the `DESC` term is ignored:

```
KEY `ix3` (`market`,`coin`,`period`,`openTime`,`high`,`low`,`a`,`b`,`c`,`d`,`e`)
```

Comment: Yes!!! Forcing the index worked. So if I understand you correctly, this feature of a descending index isn't really supported by MariaDB automatically, so I need to force it to use it?

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk Not exactly.  The descending index is not supported, so the index isn't as helpful as it might have been.  But it's still a covering index, which means it contains all the columns required to satisfy the data requirements of your query, even if the order isn't exactly correct.  This avoids having to scan the table or point accessing the table after scanning a different non-covering index.  Sometimes you can get better behavior (better access path) that the optimizer might not be able to find.

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk If `MDEV-13756` is ever completed / released, you would probably need to drop/recreate that index, since the `DESC` term was ignored when creating the new `ix3` index.  MySQL (recent versions) currently does support this.  Maria just hasn't gotten around to it yet.

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk After creating that index in MySQL 8.0, we see the following index in the result of `show create table`: `KEY ix3 (market,coin,period,openTime DESC,high,low,a,b,c,d,e)`

Answer (score 0):

The query is quite simple. You don't need a view, but a good index for it.

The index that will improve the performance of that query is:

```
create index ix1 on Candlestick (market, coin, period, openTime);
```

Comment: I have added an update to my question about indexes!

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk That's a different query. Please tell us which is the query you want to optimize, and include the current execution plan in the question.

Comment: No it's the same query, only I don't use the view in that updated query. So I first select the top 16 records, and then reverse the order of those 16 to ascending. This query results in the same result

Answer (score 0):

Even when you are querying your view. It's still the querying the table source table, getting all the rows, sorting in descending order of openTime, only then selecting top 16 rows.

After that you it's sorting the selected 16 digits in ascending order of openTime.

I agree with @The Impaler. You might need an appropriate index on that table.

Comment: I have added an update to my question about indexes!